# VueJS setInterval clearInterval issue

Tags: vue.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a VueJS slideshow component which uses `setInterval`.

I am having major issues simply calling `clearInterval` on it!

```js
  data() {
    return {
      slideIndex: 1,
    }
  },  
  mounted() {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
    this.startTimer();
  },
  methods: {
    // Timer
    startTimer() {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.plusSlides(1);
      }, 4500);
    },
    invalidateTimer() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    },

    // Next/Prev controls
    plusSlides(n) {
      this.invalidateTimer();
      this.showSlides((this.slideIndex += n));
    },
```

Calling `this.invalidateTimer()` does nothing.

I've also tried with `timer` being on the component's `data`, same result, `clearInterval` has no effect.

I'm aware this business logic is bogus, but would just like to see `clearInterval` working as desired.

How can I stop the loop?

Comment: where do you call the `this.invalidateTimer` ?

Comment: @NguyenYou from another method inside the same component (handlers for prev / next buttons)

Comment: @ChrisAllinson - Can you show more of the component's code? My first though was that `this` was not pointing to the vm, at `this.invalidateTimer()`... I hope you are using the parenthesis to call the function... The problem is probably a small detail...

Comment: original post's code updated to show where I'm testing (ie currently calling `invalidateTimer`)

Comment: @ChrisAllinson - I expect that `this.showSlides` does not call `startTimer`... Anyway, I would add a `console.log(this.timer);` at the end of `startTimer` function, and also at the beginning of `invalidateTimer`... we shall see the first `console.log` call result as soon as the component is rendered... and then the second result when the button is clicked... let us know the results.

Comment: @ChrisAllinson - Ah... `timer` belongs to `data`... try removing it from `data` (remove the `timer: '',` line)... and let us know if it works.

Comment: @J.Bruni I call `startTimer()` in `mounted()` just below `showSlides()`

Comment: where do/should I declare timer then?

Comment: @ChrisAllinson - Nowhere. It will be a common object property of the `vm`. It does not require to be "tracked" by VueJS reactivity.

Comment: Add the `console.log` lines and let us know the output...

Comment: Updated the code again ... It's now complaining about ... `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: timer is not defined"` ... the timer seems to be ticking, but it also is complaining in a loop about `_testimonial.vue?ad1b:123 Uncaught ReferenceError: timer is not defined`

Comment: To me it looks fine  - just wonder if by chance you override timer? E.g double mount? Start an interval in showSlide? Best put it into a test suite and mock unit test those method calls.

Comment: `console.log`s show `startTimer` is only ever called once, and `invalidateTimer` is called over and over with no effect!

Comment: After last update timer is not in VM scope - cannot be accessed by any other than startTimer

Comment: I have tried with timer being on the component's data ... so `this.timer` everywhere and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You shall remove it from `data`, but you need to keep using `this.timer`

Comment: And `console.log(this.timer)` at the end of `startTimer` shall output the same value of `console.log(this.timer)` at the beginning of `invalidateTimer`.

Comment: Can you pls explain what nothing works is - plusSlide gets called on and on? Can you use setTimeout instead interval? Call it past showSlide and trigger plusSlide.

Comment: My timer continues to fire `this.plusSlides(1)` which in turn calls `this.invalidateTimer()` which in turn calls `clearInterval(this.timer)` which has no effect

Answer (score -1):

Found a work around ... you can keep the `timer` on the component's `data`, determine it's `id`, then in `invalidateTimer` you can loop through every Timeout on `window` and find it ...

```
  data() {
    return {
      slideIndex: 1,
      timer: '',
      timerId: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.showSlides(this.slideIndex);
    this.startTimer();
  },
  methods: {
    // Timer
    startTimer() {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.plusSlides(1);
      }, 4500);
      this.timerId = this.timer._id
    },
    invalidateTimer() {
      var ids = window.setTimeout(function() {}, 0);
      while (ids--) {
        if (ids == this.timerId) {
          window.clearTimeout(ids);
          break;
        }
      }
    },

    // Next/Prev controls
    plusSlides(n) {
      this.invalidateTimer();
      this.startTimer();
      this.showSlides((this.slideIndex += n));
    },
```

My business logic has been updated. It invalidates the timer upon prev/next being clicked, then simply resets the timer so it will auto slide 4500ms later.